# Login form with access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, authentication

```
try
{

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=  C:\Users\jay.desai\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Jahoo Sign in form!\Jahoo Sign in form!\Registration_form.mdb");
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from Login where Username='"+txtlognUsrnm.Text+"' and Password='"+txtlognpswrd+"'", con);
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(dr.Read() == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Credentials, Please Re-Enter");
    }
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

I have created one login form and one table in microsoft access which contains username and password fields.when i click on login button it always shows else message though the username and password is same as in table.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Perhaps actually passing in the password in your query string?  `txtlognpswrd` should be `txtlognpswrd.Text`.  **HOWEVER** - please learn and use Parameterized queries to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word PASSWORD is a reserved keyword in access-jet. You need to encapsulate it in square brackets.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from Login where Username=" + 
                       "? and [Password]=?", con);
```

Also do not use string concatenation to build sql commands but a parameterized query

There are other problems in your code above.
First try to use the using statement to be sure that the connection and other disposable objects are correctly closed and disposed.
Second, if you need only to check the login credentials, then there is no need to get back the Whole record and you could use the ExecuteScalar method avoiding the OleDbDataReader object

```
string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=  C:\Users\jay.desai\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Jahoo Sign in form!\Jahoo Sign in form!\Registration_form.mdb";
string cmdText = "select Count(*) from Login where Username=? and [Password]=?"
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con))
{
     con.Open();
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtlognUsrnm.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtlognpswrd.Text);  // <- is this a variable or a textbox?
     int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()
     if(result > 0)
          MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
     else
         MessageBox.Show("Invalid Credentials, Please Re-Enter");
}
```

Comment: thank u...it was my mistake i forgot to write Text after txtLognpswrd..and yeah  parameterized query is also great concept...thanks again